# jQuery traversing HTML through $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an HTML document structured in the following way:

```
<section id="page1" data-role="page"> 
    <a href="#" id="next-section" class="next-section" style=" cursor:e-resize"><div class="arearight" alt="go right" ></div></a>
    <a href="#" id="prev-section" class="prev-section" style=" cursor:w-resize"><div class="arealeft" alt="go left" ></div></a>
...   
</section>

<!-- more sections -->
```

And I have the following code to traverse it

```
$(":jqmData(role='page')").each(function() {
    $(this).bind("swipeleft" goLeft); //goLeft and goRight are defined and working
    $(this).bind("swipeleft", goRight);
    //...
}
```

The swipe is working fine, but I would like to bind to the `next-section` and `prev-section` a `click` behaviour to call `goLeft` and `goRight`, but I don't know how to access them through the `$(this)` object. Does anybody have an idea how to get to them?

Thanks

Comment: Just some notes for you: you can use chain method call in jquery. It brings you some optimization. Like $(this).bind("ss", ss).bind("dd", dd); Also, note, that "bind" method is called deprecated in jquery. You should use "on" mtthod to provide better compatibility with current jquery version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a different selector for them:

```
$(this).find("#prev-section").click(goLeft);

$(this).find("#next-section").click(goRight);
```

Notice that you'll have multiple elements with the same ID (#prev-section, #next-section), but IDs are supposed to be unique on the entire DOM. Replace it with classes or data-dash attributes (like the one you're using for `role=page`).

Comment: I suppose, you didn't get the question. The point was to get  those NodeElements from current context, not just bind the click event and get some context there.

Comment: @VladislavQulin I can't see it in the question. Do you mean each ":jqmData(role='page')" is a parent of such links (with the same ID!)?

Comment: Yes, that was the question. Look, he walks throughout some nodes, attaching event listeners for all inner links and block itself. So the question was to get needed links from current block context.

Comment: I would also recommend using "find" method instead of "children". Yes, it's a bit slower, but it disattach your JS code from HTML code, which is better in terms of supporting code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#next-section').bind('click', goRight);
$('#prev-section').bind('click', goLeft);
```

or

```
$('a.next-section').bind('click', goRight);
$('a.prev-section').bind('click', goLeft);
```

or

```
$(this).children('#next-section').bind("swipeleft" goLeft);
$(this).children('#prev-section').bind("swipeleft", goRight);
```

or

```
$(this).find('#next-section').bind("swipeleft" goLeft);
$(this).find('#prev-section').bind("swipeleft", goRight);
```

Comment: Don't you ever use that sort of selector in your code (a#next-section). Id selector should go solo.